# What is wrong in the code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I am very newbie to programming and stack overflow. I choose python as my first language. Today as I was writing some code to refresh and to improve my skills I wrote a little program. But with complete errors.
Here is the Program

```
a = [1 , 2, 3]

def list_append():
    numbers = int(raw_input("Enter the number please")) 
    a.append(numbers)
    print a

def average(list):
    for marks in list:
        print marks
    total = float(sum(list))
    total = total / len(list)
    print ("Your total average is : %d"  %total )

def loop():
        add_numbers = raw_input("Do you want to add another number")
        if add_numbers == ("y"):
            return list_append()
        else:
            return average()

while True:
        loop()  

print average(a)
```

Basically the function of this program is to ask user for the input of the number. Then append to the list and then show the average which is an easy one.

But I want the program to stop after the first input and ask user if they want to give another input ?

Can't understand where is the problem. ** I am not asking for the direct solution. I would rather want an explanation than the solution itself.**

Comment: Well, `while True` seems to be your problem.

Comment: this is not a "direct solution" but it may help: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is missing in your code:

1. Need to break any loop, your while loop in going into infinite loop.

`while True:
        loop()`

 2. Handle exception during type casting.

`numbers = int(raw_input("Enter the number please"))`

3. Create user enter number list in loop function and pass to list_append function to add numbers.
   Also return from the loop function to pass argument into average function.

code:

```
def list_append(numbers):
    while 1:
        try:
            no = int(raw_input("Enter the number please:")) 
            numbers.append(no)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter only number."
    return list(numbers)

def average(number_list):
    avg = float(sum(number_list))/ len(number_list)
    return avg

def loop():
    numbers = []
    while 1:
        add_numbers = raw_input("you want to add number in list(Y):")
        if add_numbers.lower()== ("y"):
            numbers = list_append(numbers)
        else:
            return list(numbers)

numbers = loop()  
avg = average(numbers)

print "User enter numbers:", numbers
print "average value of all enter numbers:", avg
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 17.py 
you want to add number in list(Y):y
Enter the number please:10
you want to add number in list(Y):y
Enter the number please:e
Enter only number.
Enter the number please:20
you want to add number in list(Y):Y
Enter the number please:30
you want to add number in list(Y):n
User enter numbers: [10, 20, 30]
average value of all enters numbers: 20.0
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```

---

do not use variable names which are already define by python
e.g. `list`

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
>>> list([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list = [2]
>>> list([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: Thank You for the awesome answer. Never knew you can use the while loop in between defining a function. THANKS...

Comment: Can you also tell me what does the `while 1: ` do. Is it same as `while true:` ??

Comment: both are same. Code will enter in while loop only when condition is `True`. Only need to break while loop, In above case when user enter character other than `Y` or `y`  then return from the function .

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
def average(list):
    total = float(sum(list))
    total = total / len(list)
    print ("Your total average is : %d"  %total )

while True:
    numbers = raw_input("Enter the number please or 'q' to quit : ")
    if numbers == "q":
        average(a)
        break
    else:
        a.append(int(numbers))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: based on your function :)